# How to replace countries other than 'India' and 'U.S.A' by 'Other' in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Q0_0': ["India", "Algeria", "India", "U.S.A", "Morocco", "Tunisia", "U.S.A", "France", "Russia", "Algeria"],
    'Q1_1': [np.random.randint(1,100) for i in range(10)],
    'Q1_2': np.random.random(10),
    'Q1_3': np.random.randint(2, size=10),
    'Q2_1': [np.random.randint(1,100) for i in range(10)],
    'Q2_2': np.random.random(10),
    'Q2_3': np.random.randint(2, size=10)
})
```

It has following display:

|  | Q0_0 | Q1_1 | Q1_2 | Q1_3 | Q2_1 | Q2_2 | Q2_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | India | 21 | 0.326856 | 0 | 51 | 0.520506 | 0 |
| 1 | Algeria | 7 | 0.504580 | 1 | 43 | 0.953744 | 1 |
| 2 | India | 67 | 0.327273 | 1 | 34 | 0.840453 | 1 |
| 3 | U.S.A | 49 | 0.056478 | 0 | 67 | 0.309559 | 1 |
| 4 | Morocco | 71 | 0.743913 | 1 | 76 | 0.240706 | 1 |
| 5 | Tunisia | 31 | 0.060707 | 1 | 78 | 0.576598 | 0 |
| 6 | U.S.A | 25 | 0.588239 | 1 | 61 | 0.133856 | 1 |
| 7 | France | 99 | 0.991723 | 0 | 85 | 0.274825 | 1 |
| 8 | Russia | 9 | 0.846950 | 1 | 61 | 0.279948 | 1 |
| 9 | Algeria | 79 | 0.176326 | 1 | 78 | 0.881051 | 1 |

I need to change countries other than `India` and `U.S.A` to `Òther` in column `Q0_0`.

**Desired output**

```
Q0_0    Q1_1    Q1_2    Q1_3    Q2_1    Q2_2    Q2_3
0   India     21    0.326856    0   51  0.520506    0
1   Other      7    0.504580    1   43  0.953744    1
2   India     67    0.327273    1   34  0.840453    1
3   U.S.A     49    0.056478    0   67  0.309559    1
4   Other     71    0.743913    1   76  0.240706    1
5   Other     31    0.060707    1   78  0.576598    0
6   U.S.A     25    0.588239    1   61  0.133856    1
7   Other     99    0.991723    0   85  0.274825    1
8   Other     9 0.846950    1   61  0.279948    1
9   Other     79    0.176326    1   78  0.881051    1
```

I tried to use `pandas.series.str.replace()` but it didn't work.

Any help from your side will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`pandas.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) :

```
df["Q0_0"]= df["Q0_0"].mask(~df["Q0_0"].isin(["India", "U.S.A"])).fillna("Other")
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

    Q0_0  Q1_1      Q1_2  Q1_3  Q2_1      Q2_2  Q2_3
0  India    43  0.681795     0    36  0.772289     0
1  Other    85  0.695352     1    14  0.989219     1
2  India    69  0.684015     1    85  0.687373     0
3  U.S.A    10  0.175235     1    52  0.825989     1
4  Other    90  0.998192     0    59  0.482667     0
5  Other    27  0.723308     0    90  0.054042     1
6  U.S.A    38  0.973819     0    69  0.536380     1
7  Other    10  0.815710     1     2  0.134707     1
8  Other    38  0.238863     1     1  0.872125     1
9  Other    96  0.078010     0    84  0.650347     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
df['Q0_0'] = df['Q0_0'].str.replace('Algeria', 'Other')
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, because we won't know which country names are present ahead of time. We want to replace "everything that isn't either `India` or `U.S.A.`; we don't want to hard-code the things to look for and replace.